# Generate JSON Schema with AnyOf/OneOf/AllOf

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to use Newtonsoft JSON.Net Schema to generate schemas from my POCOs.  JSON Schema supports the idea of combining sub-schemas via [anyOf/oneOf/allOf](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html).  I can't figure out how to make this work with JSON.Net Schema.  I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/120), but there's no resolution there, though there is a reference to using the `KnownTypeAttribute` but then a comment that it doesn't work.
Any pointers on generating schemas with anyOf/oneOf/allOf?

Comment: Did you find workaround for anyOf/OneOf/allOf?

Comment: No.  I ended up writing code that would open the generated schema as JSON and using 
 System.Text.Json to add the allOf elements I needed.